# Unable to run Node.js app on DirectAdmin shared hosting: sh: /.../nodeApp/node_modules/.bin/nodeApp: Permission denied

Tags: node.js, shared-hosting, permission-denied, virtual-environment

I am trying to start a node app on a DirectAdmin shared hosting. Due to limitations of that particular hoster, I could not `run npm install`; I had to upload the entire app, node_modules included. Now, when I attempt to `npm run start` the app from the node virtual environment, the script fails with the following error:

```
sh: /.../MyNodeApp/node_modules/.bin/MyNodeApp: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! MyNodeApp@0.1.0 start: `MyNodeApp start`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the MyNodeApp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have followed the steps in the [Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) NPM guide for this, but I am still getting the same error.

How can I start the app?

Comment: Either the user that runs it doesn't have permissions, and for that you can use `chown` recursively on all the files/folders in the project, or alternatively,  use `chmod` to allow execution permissions on the relevant files.

Comment: I've just done that (`chmod 777`) but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Then try the first thing I mentioned (chown).

Comment: I actually failed to apply `chmod` recursively to the entire folder, it works now, thanks!